# Combining two integrals with respect to different measures

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are finite and non-negative measures. I am curious if, given those two assumptions, is it always the case that

$\int_{x \in A} f(x) d\mu_1 (x) + \int_{x \in A} f(x) d\mu_2 (x) = \int_{x \in A} f(x) d(\mu_1 (x) + \mu_2 (x))$

ie. Provided the integral bound and integrated function are identical, can we combine measures like this into sums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If $\mu$ is prescribed on measurable sets by $$B\mapsto\mu_1(B)+\mu_2(B)\tag1$$ then $\mu$ is a measure and equality $(1)$ concerning measurable sets can easily be expanded to integrable functions $f$ resulting in:$$f\mapsto\int fd\mu_1+\int fd\mu_2$$

This by going the usual way: characteristic function $\to$ simple function $\to$ nonnegative measurable function  $\to$ integrable function.

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing if we allow $\mu_1$ or $\mu_2$ to possibly be infinite this is no longer true, due to issues of adding/subtracting infinity. Is this correct?

Comment: That is not really problematic. Then $\int fd(\mu_1+\mu_2)=\int fd\mu_1+\int fd\mu_2$ still holds if $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function or is a nonpositive measurable function or is a function that is both $\mu_1$- and $\mu_2$-integrable.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.